# Inverse et réciproque dans le contexte mathématique : différence entre le français et l'anglais

Tags: vocabulaire, anglais, usage, étymologie, mathématiques

En français on dit, fonction réciproque (p.ex. arcsin et sin) et fonction inverse (p.ex. 1/x et x). En anglais les termes sont, respectivement, inverse function et reciprocal function. Y a-t-il une raison pour cette différence pour cette paire de mots ?

Comment: Esprit de contradiction ?

Comment: Reciprocal identities are the reciprocals of the three standard trigonometric functions, namely sine, cosine, and tangent. **In trigonometry, reciprocal identities are sometimes called inverse identities**. Reciprocal identities are inverse sine, cosine, and tangent functions written as “arc” prefixes such as arcsine, arccosine, and arctan. For instance, functions like sin^-1 (x) and cos^-1 (x) are inverse identities. **Either notation is correct and acceptable**. https://owlcation.com/stem/Reciprocal-Identities-in-Trigonometry-With-Examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Je cite Michel Queysanne, *Algèbre*, Armand Colin, 1964.

- «  Certains auteurs disent *fonction inverse* pour  « fonction réciproque  d'une bijection ». Cet usage est à proscrire, car si *f* est par exemple une application de A dans R<sup>*</sup> l'inverse de *f* est l'application définie par *x→ 1/f(x)* ».

Il existe cependant un autre problème, et cela est le fait que le terme « fonction » en français n'est pas utilisé traditionnellement pour « fonction » dans le contexte de l'analyse mathématique ni dans le contexte de la théorie des ensembles où on y préfère encore le terme « application », le seul terme que l'on ait  utilisé jusqu'à ce que sous l'influence des mathématiques anglo-saxonnes on commence à utiliser le terme général « fonction » en analyse. Le terme général est utilisé en français (traditionnellement) dans la théorie des ensembles, ce que l'on peut vérifier dans *Bourbaki* (*Théorie des Ensembles, E II p.13 (fonction) et p. 14 (application)*), où est défini la fonction d'un ensemble général vers un autre et l'application (aussi d'un ensemble général vers un autre). La différence est que, lorsque l'on parle de la fonction *f* de *A* vers *B*, *A* est compris comme étant un ensemble de **départ** et lorsque l'on parle de l'application *f* de *A* vers *B*, *B* doit être l'ensemble de **définition** de *f*. On peut vérifier les faits de base mentionnés ci-dessus aussi dans « *Ramis Deschamps  Odoux, Cours de mathématiques 1. Algèbre, Masson, 1964 p. 11 et 12 ».

Ceci montre que la question  n'a pas de réponse dans le contexte d'une terminologie unique anglais-français, parce que cette terminologie unique n'existe pas au moment où les définitions de « réciproque » et « inverse » sont considérées. Elle  n'a commencé à s'insinuer, et cela de plus en plus fortement, que depuis quelques temps.

Answer (score 1):

Le sens de *to invert* en maths est *to undo/to revert* et l'anglais *inverse* couvre tout element qui permet d'annuler une operation, soit l'inverse, l'opposé et la réciproque français.

L'opération entre un élément et son *inverse* anglais donne toujours l'élément neutre. On trouve donc plusieurs *inverses* en anglais:

- *[additive inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Additive_inverse)*, equivalent de l'opposé français, qui annule une addition en produisant l'élément neutre de l'addition, soit 0.
- *[multiplicative inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_inverse)*, equivalent de l'inverse français, qui annule une multiplication en produisant l'élément neutre de la multiplication, soit 1.
- *[inverse function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function)*, equivalent de fonction réciproque, dont la composition produit l'élément neutre de la composition, soit la fonction identité. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function) indique: "*a function that undoes the operation of ƒ*".
- *[inverse trigonometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions)* est simplement *the inverse function* d'une fonction trigonométrique, soit sa réciproque.

Il existe des synonymes:

- *opposite* pour *additive inverse*
- *reciprocal* pour *multiplicative inverse*. Ainsi la *[reciprocal function](https://calculus.subwiki.org/wiki/Reciprocal_function)* est la [function inverse](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonction_inverse) française.

Answer (score -1):

Il semble qu'en français, le mot "inverse" soit réservé à la transformation d'un nombre en son diviseur, c'est pourquoi le mot "*réciproque*" est employé pour désigner le contraposé logique d'un objet mathématique, et non sa seule inversion arithmétique: "*réciproque*" est donc plus conceptuel, et "*inverse*" plus précis: l'inversion est alors un cas particulier de réciprocité, comme le carré est un cas particulier du rectangle.

Il semble que les Anglo-saxons aient fait un choix différent dans l'usage de ces termes. Ce n'est pas la première fois qu'*ils nous les brisent menu*!

Comment: Je ne pense pas que les Anglo-saxons avaient une mathématique si avancée.